# Making a popup modal (containing a Custom UserControl)

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm looking at updating some existing code and making a popup modal which contains a custom user control and wondering if this is possible?

I know if I was to place the custom UserControl inside another form this could be achieved quite easily but this seems a bit overkill.

(CommentBox is the custom control)

```
CommentBox comment = CommentManager.GetComments(commentType, foreignID);

.//Some code to determine location of the popup
.
.
Popup popup = new Popup(comment);
popup.Show(grid.PointToScreen(viewerLocation));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it has to be modal, then you have to use a form.

If you are just needing it to pop up over the form, then look into `ToolStripDropDown` and `ToolStripControlHost` to provide that ability.  Here is an example: [Padding/ Size / Margin, when using ToolstripControlHost for a popup control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8099941/719186)

Comment: Cheers for that, I'm guessing ToolStripDown and ToolStripControlHost can't be made modal as well?

Comment: @Standage No, because they have a form for that.  If you need it modal, you can always just create a form in code and add your control to it with a Dock.Fill type style, etc.